# Finding Label Before Input[required]

Tags: jquery, input, label

My simple form fields look like so:

```
 <div class="form-group " id="requestor_last_name-input">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="requestor_last_name">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="requestor_last_name" id="requestor_last_name" size="50" maxlength="50" value="Flaherty" required>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I don't understand why I cannot select the label before my input[required] like this:

```
$("input[required]").prev("label").css("color", "red");
```

What am i missing?

Comment: The `label` is not a sibling, you need to transverse the DOM and select the parent, *then* the previous `label` - `$("input[required]").parent().prev("label")`

Comment: `prev('label')` selects the previous sibling *only if* it is a label. `<input>` doesn't have any (element) siblings. Docs: https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: lame. .prev() "Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector." Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prev()` only selects siblings and since the INPUT is the only child of its parent DIV, it has no siblings.  So you need to use `.parent()` to get to the DIV, and then you can use `.prev()` to get to the label.

```
$("input[required]").parent().prev("label").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by assigning a id to div containing control label.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert( $("#inputdiv").prev(".control-label").html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group " id="requestor_last_name-input">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="requestor_last_name">Last Name</label>
      <div id="inputdiv" class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="requestor_last_name" id="requestor_last_name" size="50" maxlength="50" value="Flaherty" required>
      </div>
    </div>



<button>Get Label</button>
```

Comment: A little bit more than i need, but helpful in demonstrating the requirements! Thanks ;)